# How to test button that on click renders html element within the same component in React testing library, Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

My OrderModuleHeader is a clickable div that renders div when clicked like shown below:

```
 const [orderModuleIsOpen, setOrderModuleIsOpen] = useState(true);

render (
<div>

     <OrderModuleHeader data-testid="orderModuleHeaderButton"
              onClick={() => setOrderModuleIsOpen(!orderModuleIsOpen)}
            >
              <NavigationArrow>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={orderModuleIsOpen ? faChevronUp : faChevronDown}
                  className="fa-xs"
                />
              </NavigationArrow>
     </OrderModuleHeader>
            {orderModuleIsOpen && (
              <OrderModuleBody>Some content</OrderModuleBody>
)
 </div>)
```

So div OrderModuleBody is displayed only when we click the button.

I started my test by the following:

```
describe('Expand body button', () => {
it('should render OrderModuleBody when clicked', () => {
      const button = screen.getByTestId('orderModuleHeaderButton');
      
      fireEvent.change() ... 
    });
}
```

I realize that I made div clickable and in test I call it a button.

I don't know what exactly I need to write in fireEvent to test if OrderModuleBody (div) renders on click.

NOTE: I'm not allowed to bring in shallow method from Enzyme or use any other testing frameworks except Jest, React testing library.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to render your component in order to test it. You then access the button after which you simulate a button click, and then eventually expect your change to occur.

The testing library has a function named `userEvent` which can simulate a button click.

```
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

describe('Expand body button', async () => {
    it('should render OrderModuleBody when clicked', () => {
        // render your component
        render(<YourComponent />) 
        // access your button
        const button = screen.getByTestId('orderModuleHeaderButton') 
        // simulate button click
        userEvent.click(button); 

        // expect result
        await waitFor(() =>  
            expect(screen.getByText("Some content")).toBeInTheDocument();
       });
}
```

Comment: I said "Some content", sorry for not clarifying this. There is a bunch of HTML elements in there instead of string 'Some context'. What do I write instead of queryByText  in this case?

Comment: queryByRole('div') didn't work. Error 'received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement. Received has value: null'

Comment: My bad I believe its: `screen.getByText("Some content")`

Comment: You can `getByText()` based on any string that is part of your content. Alternatively, use your method for `test-id` or any other that youre comfortable with.

Comment: Any ideas why it throws an error: " TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="unassigned-tab"]. Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />" 
I've imported the component and added data-testid="unassigned-tab" to one div in my content.
I don't understand why it doesn't see it?

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to say why you dont see it. However, you could try awaiting the rendering of the compont. Please note that I've added `async` and `await waitFor()` to the code example above.

Comment: what if the `Button` is an svg icon(no text) and it comes from a framework that doesn't allow `testId` to pass into the props? I can only pass in a regular `id` or a `classname`?

Comment: Then you can use  the regular `document.getElementById('id')` or
`document.querySelector('.class-name')` see [this](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/683#issuecomment-860781713) src. Alternatively you should be able to do `screen.getByRole('button')` but this can be require further filtering if you have multiple buttons in your component.